# How to apply multiple CSS selectors to a paticular div?

Tags: css

I'm creating a kind of CMS. In this system, each editor can define their own CSS like below.
This style should be applied to their own articles.

```
<style>
p{
color:blue;text-align:center;
}
a{
color:red;
}
</style>
```

These styles must be applied to a particular div, in this case `id="editors_area"`.

```
<body>
    <div id="editors_area">
        ===Styles should be applied only here.===
        Each editors article are displayed in this area.
    </div>
    ===Styles should NOT be applied here.===
</body>
```

To achieve this, I have a plan to insert `#editors_area` into editor's CSS, as a descendant selector on serve side like below.

```
<style>
#editors_area p{
color:blue;text-align:center;
}
#editors_area a{
color:red;
}
</style>
```

But I guess there are more simple ways to achieve above requirement.

**EDIT** 
I deleted the javascript code. Which was not suited here.

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to do some serverside processing of the CSS to modify the selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SASS and SCSS give you the ability to do stuff like this (unless I'm totally missing the point of you're question, which is possible as I'm about as far as you get from a front end person).

Something like:

```
#editors_area
    a 
        color:blue
        text-align:center
    p
        color:red
```

Depending on what language you're working in, it might be worth checking out. I've seen implementations for Ruby, Python, PHP and Java, although I've only used Ruby's myself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just checked SASS ans SCSS. These could be what I wanted. I'll study them from now on.

Comment: SASS and SCSS are ways of generating CSS code, and the CSS code would still have something like `#editors_area p`. In a simple case, SASS and SCSS would not really help much.

Answer (score 5):

CSS was designed for this, so your first method is the correct one -- not to mention that the jQuery method you have wouldn't work.

You should only use jQuery to change `css` properties when it is required after page load, and even then you should use `addClass()` or `removeClass()` and have those classes defined in your CSS file. This is a better separation of concerns.

Comment: Thank you Rory McCrossan, You are right. I should have not wrote the code which dosen't work. Please understand I just tried to say that somebody has a idea with javascript.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to make it clear that CSS was specifically designed for the task you require.

Answer (score 1):

you try this

```
$("#editors_area > *").css("color","blue"); // * may be p or a whatever
```

Comment: Thank you Mishu Sarker, I appreciate your advice. It could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are finding a way to insert CSS blocks dynamically from jQuery, then you can do as follows:

```
$('<style type="text/css">
    #editors_area p {
       color:blue;text-align:center;
    }
    #editors_area a {
       color:red;
    }
    </style>').appendTo('head');
```

Comment: You can, **but please don't**

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I agree it's not recommended as a general rule, but it could be useful in specific scenarios, OP's commented each editor could edit their CSS, in this case I prefer this solution rather than writing .css files on-the-fly with content from the db.

Comment: @Nelson, Thank you very much for your advice. And thank you for reading the my requement deeply. This was very helpful.

Comment: @naoki I'm glad this was helpful to you, you can thank with an upvote too :-)